# CSS - scroll to id but need to show h3 element above id

Tags: javascript, html, css

Normally, when scrolling to any section in HTML, only add id and add `href=#id`.

In my case, I have a `<h3>` tag above id, need to show it first.

Have any method to do it with CSS?

Another question, have any javascript (not jQuery) to smooth scroll when scrolling with a link to the id of an element?

My example code:

```html
<a href="#nan-txt">Click here</a>
<h3 style="height: 500px;">NEW TEXT AT HERE</h3>
<p id="nan-txt">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

Comment: In my real project, it should padding-top 30px, in this example, I add `500px` to easily imagine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to set `id` to `h3` tag. But if you can't the best options is set `padding` and negative `margin`.
Example in the snippet below.

Is a lot of smooth scroll scripts, I always use this: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

```css
.space {
  height: 3000px;
}

h3 {
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}

#one {
  height: 3000px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#one">Click!</a>
<div class="space"></div>
<h3>Title of H3</h3>
<p id="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer id risus consectetur, lobortis justo sed, feugiat ipsum. Suspendisse quis enim lacus. Curabitur lorem dolor, lobortis id metus quis, venenatis accumsan dui. Duis metus est, consectetur dignissim
  porta sodales, accumsan sit amet magna. Vestibulum id metus mauris. Etiam aliquet quam in est viverra, ut posuere nunc scelerisque. Morbi in ligula id mi iaculis pulvinar. Aliquam erat volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
  montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus in lorem at massa molestie commodo aliquam sollicitudin augue. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus ultrices viverra mattis. Aenean rhoncus nibh a rhoncus congue. Nulla feugiat orci eget auctor venenatis. Integer a vehicula
  nunc, vitae aliquet sem. Aliquam scelerisque nisl non risus feugiat, sit amet efficitur ligula convallis.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be an unorthodox answer, but I propose you move the id to the element you want to scroll to:

```html
<a href="#nan-txt">Click here</a>
<h3 id="nan-txt" style="height: 500px;">NEW TEXT AT HERE</h3>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

Comment: yeah. I understand. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `h3` tag inside `nan-txt` element. So that it will stop on `h3`.

Regarding smooth scrolling, add `scroll-behavior: smooth` style to your `html`.

See the Snippet below:

```css
html{
scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<a href="#nan-txt">Click here</a>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p id="nan-txt">
<h3 style="height: 500px;">NEW TEXT AT HERE</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

Comment: Note that `hx` tags are not valid content for `p` tags : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p

Comment: @JonP That's a good point. Thanks man. I will keep that in mind!